# how do i make MFC SDI Client window Non-movable?

Tags: mfc

i have re sized the client window initially and also made it non-re sizable. Only problem, i am facing right now is when i move the window ( drag title bar left or right ) , the contents in it disappears that is why i want to make it fixed at top left until termination.

BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{

```
if( !CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
    return FALSE;
// TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
//  the CREATESTRUCT cs
cs.x=0;
cs.y=0;
// Create a window without min/max buttons or sizable border
cs.style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_BORDER;

return TRUE;
```

}

here is my OnDraw() :

```
void CblockmaniaView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CblockmaniaDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    CImage* img= new CImage();
    pDC->FillSolidRect( 0, 0,810,640, RGB(128,128,128));

    for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
         for (int j=0;j<16;j++)
         {
             if (updateInfo[j]==true)
             {
                 if (GetDocument()->x.map[i][j]!=NULL)
                 {
                     x=GetDocument()->x.map[i][j]->x;
                     y=GetDocument()->x.map[i][j]->y;
                     img->Load(GetDocument()->x.map[i][j]->imgPath); 
                     img->Draw(pDC->m_hDC,40*y,40*x, 40, 40);
                     img->Destroy();
                 }  
             }
         }
    }

    if (firstRun)
    {   
        pDC->FillSolidRect( 640, 0, 10,640, RGB(0,0,0));
        img->Load(L"C:\\Users\\Ad33l's\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\block mania\\block mania\\res\\score.png"); 
        img->Draw(pDC->m_hDC,655,25,150,30);
        img->Destroy();
    }

    for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        updateInfo[i]=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Is it that you don't want the window moved, or, is moving the window causing a problem with the way it's painted?

Comment: yeh , dragging the window with mouse (i.e moving it) is causing problem , so i just want to restrict movement or make it non-movable.

Comment: So moving the window is causing a problem with the drawing?  You didn't explicitly say that.

Comment: yeah , can u suggest any solution ? i've drawn rectangles with fillSolidRect() , and loaded some images and i'm updating view with
invalidateRect()

Comment: Assuming you have a view class, hopefully, you're doing the drawing from within the view class (eg. OnDraw ()) and re-drawing the view in response to a move message.

Comment: yeah drawing in OnDraw() in view class , and update on mouse click , because it is a recursive game

Comment: I bet you are somehow drawing at the screen origin not the window origin and this is causing the problem. Can you post the code of your `OnDraw()` method otherwise we cannot help..

Comment: Making the window non movable istn't the correct approach!

Comment: i have posted onDraw()

Comment: Your img->Draw call seems very unreasonable. Why are you multiplying x and y by 40?

Comment: because every square brick image is of 40x40 size

Comment: So x and y are indexes of the square location? In that case why don't you just use i and j from your for loops instead of retrieving them from a map?

Comment: x and y represent starting coordinate of each brick , here i've already created bricks in 2D 16x16 array named "map" , now i just retrieve each brick's coordinates and multiply them with size in order to provide dimensions and starting point for displaying on screen. these are displayed like : 
[][][][][][]
[][][][][][]
[][][][][][] etc

Comment: further , everything in background data management is correct and working perfectly , i.e no core dump or null pointer exception etc , m just having issues with display ... probably because i have not used picture controller method :
fileName = dlg.GetNextPathName(fileNamesPosition);
m_image.Load(_T(fileName)); // just change extension to load jpg
m_bitmap.Attach(m_image.Detach());
m_IconList.SetBitmap(m_bitmap);...

Comment: I'm not saying you should have an exception or anything, just that if you store the absolute coordinates for each brick and multiply by 40 you would get drastically wrong locations. The indices of the bricks within the map are enough to give you their location on screen. So for the first brick x and y should be 0, for the one to the right of it, it should be 1 and 0 and so forth.

Comment: everything is pretty much fine , problem was : in order to reduce flickers , i had a strict control structure in OnDraw() code which was causing problems , now that i have used " double-buffer" to eliminate flickers , everything is correct now